# How do I create a desktop shortcut that turns on/off a service?

Tags: service, windows-10, shortcut-file

I would be grateful if you could write me a piece of code that can make a desktop shortcut turn a service on/off.

Firstly, I feel like I should mention that I have no experience coding in any language. Hence, I am unable to provide any failed attempts at resolving this matter.

Secondly, the operating system I am using is Windows 10 Home. The service, which I would like the desktop shortcut to turn on/off, is called SCP DSx Service.

Overall, I want someone to write me a piece of code that can make a desktop shortcut turn a service on/off. In addition, I have no experience coding in any language and the operating system I'm using is Windows 10 Home. Also, the service is labelled SCP DSx Service.

Comment: The main problem you have is figuring out how to start/stop a service from the commands line. If you did a search for, say, "start Windows service command line" you'd get some ideas. Do you need it to be one shortcut to toggle (hard), or would one for on and another for off (easy) do?

Comment: I need a file on my desktop that can turn the service on and off. If I launch it while the service is off, it turns on. If I launch it while the service is on, it turns off. Anyhow, the service can be found in the Services program.

Answer (score 0):

I found you question when looking for the same solution.
Here's what I cam up with.

Create a powershell script file eg startstop.ps1 and put the following in it

```
If ((Get-Service YourService).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Service YourService} ELSE { Stop-Service YourService}
```

change **YourService** as required, note that is the service name not the display name.

Save the file and then create a shortcut and put that on your desktop.

- right click the shortcut and select properties edit the target location to include **powershell.exe -f** in front of the filename
- apply the change
- now click on advanced and tick run as administrator
- save it and you should now be able to start stop the service by clicking the shortcut.

You will get the admin prompt but I haven't found a way around that unless logged in as administrator

Hope that helps

Keith